# What's the usage of the double exclamations?

Tags: haskell

In the Data.ByteString.Internal, the ByteString has constructor

```
PS !!(ForeignPtr Word8) !!Int !!Int
```

What does these double exclamations mean here? I searched and just got that (!!) can be used to index a list `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`.

Comment: It is usually used for *strict* evaluation (in contrast to *lazy evaluation*) so the operands are evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I remember one exclamation mark (!) can make the operands strict, does double exclamations do the same?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#ByteString - where did you see your code?

Comment: @melpomene From an old version http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.1.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#t%3AByteString. Is that an outdated usage?

Comment: @hliu Looks like a rendering bug in haddock; see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.1.4/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#ByteString for the actual source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not part of the actual Haskell source but an (undocumented) feature of how Haddock renders unboxed data types. See https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-January/054135.html:

> 2009/1/21 Stephan Friedrichs <...>:
>
> > Hi,
> >
> > using haddock-2.4.1 and this file:
> >
> > > ```
> > > module Test where
> > >
> > > data Test
> > >     = NonStrict Int
> > >     | Strict !Int
> > >     | UnpackedStrict {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
> > > ```
> >
> > The generated documentation looks like this:
> >
> > ```
> > data Test
> > Constructors
> >  NonStrict Int
> >  Strict !Int
> >  UnpackedStrict !!Int
> > ```
> >
> > Note the double '!' in the last constructor. This is not intended
> >     behaviour, is it?
>
> This is the way GHC pretty prints unboxed types, so I thought Haddock
>   should follow the same convention. Hmm, perhaps Haddock should have a
>   chapter about language extensions in its documentation, with a
>   reference to the GHC documentation. That way the language used is at
>   least documented. Not sure if it helps in this case though, since "!!"
>   is probably not documented there.
>
> Perhaps we should not display unbox annotations at all since they are
>   an implementation detail, right? We could display one "!" instead,
>   indicating that the argument is strict.
>
> David